# Java Socket client/server pair can only send one message at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

A successful conversation can be carried out between the client and the server. However this is only if one message is sent between the client and server.

Example (Works):

```
Client: Hello
Server: helloo
Client: what time is it
Server: Let me get that for you
```

Example (Does not work):

```
Client: Hello
Server: helloo
Server: *How are you today*
Server: *test message*
Client: Yes
```

The messages between the asterisks do not appear on the client side untill the client sends 2 messages. From what I understand it seems to work like a net-message system where the number of messages sent by the server has to equal n+-1 the number of messages sent by the client, for all the messages to be shown.

**Client Side Code:**

```
try {
            Socket client_socket= new Socket(hostname,port_number);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String fromUser,fromServer;
            while ((fromServer=input.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println("Server: "+fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Quit")) {
                    break;
                } 
                fromUser=stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: "+fromUser);
                    output.println(fromUser);
                }

            }

        }
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
try {
            ServerSocket server_socket=new ServerSocket(port_number);
            Socket client_socket= server_socket.accept();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            output.println("Established");
            String fromUser, fromServer;
            while ((fromUser=input.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println("Client: "+fromUser);
                if (fromUser.equals("Quit")) {
                    break;
                } 
                fromServer=stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromServer!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Server: "+fromServer);
                    output.println(fromServer);
                }
            }

        }
```

Looking at the code I can see why this would happen, its because the SOP after the `While` loop initialization stops the code waiting for 1 line of input, and then waits to send its own sentence, before receiving another. I tried putting these within the if statements, but this results in no communication at all.

I cant seem to figure out how to fix this.

If this requires threads, is there another way? (i'm not too familiar with threads)

Comment: You need to take more time learning how TCP sockets work. There are countless examples of your problem out there

Comment: many of the examples i went through had the issue where only one message would send. And subsequent messages would only show up when the socket was closed. Also, I did try looking for more examples and reading up on them, couldn't seem to find a lot (some went into threading)

Comment: You haven't looked hard enough, this isnt some unique obscure use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the nature of your program, i would advise you to use more threads to handle messaging.

Lets start with the server:
If the server can have multiple clients, than it probably would be wise to distinguish every client with a thread, for example:

```
            ServerSocket ss;

            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(portIn);
                while (true) {
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    // Option 1: runnable class
                    new Thread(new CustomRunnableClass(s)).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Or if you dont want your "session manager" to be a custom runnable class, you can replace the line `new Thread(new CustomRunnableClass(s)).start();` with the following

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        new SomeClass().runThisClass();
   }
}
```

On the client side i would suggest that whatever class that listens to new messages from sockets will be distinguished by a new thread:

```
private void startListening() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(;;) {
                String msg = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("  ----- Recieved New Message -----\n" + msg);
                for (IMessageListener listener : listeners) {
                    try {
                        listener.onMessageRecieved(msg);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

this way the client listens to any message received by the client and runs a method to handle them upon receiving, and is not hung in the meanwhile.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: After reading this.. i took a quick crash-course on threads, if I understand this correctly, the server accepts a new socket connection and passes it to a thread.. so all that Bufferereading and printwriting will be within a `public void run` method somewhere else. However, I still do not see how this would fix the issue (same while loop will be in the thread as well). Im not too sure what is being done on the client side though? is it a thread for listening and regular main method for posting?

Answer (score -1):

you need non-blocking sockets, the reader function should return intermediately if there is no data in the input buffer.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0070__Java_Network_Non-Blocking_Socket.htm

Comment: usage of threads can solve the problem this time, but in  real servers is a bad idea to create a thread for each incoming socket, imagine how many threads would have the http server that is running stackoverflow

Comment: You might be surprised how many. You don't have any evidence that SO servers aren't using threads. You haven't actually identified what the problem is in this question. Poor quality tutorial.

Comment: the problem is that the function readline does not return control until data is available. this problem is solved with non-blocking IO.

Comment: as the number of threads exceeds the number of cores, performance begins to drop due to permutations context of cores shared by more than 1 thread